# input[type="submit" i] - What is "i" and this syntax

Tags: css, google-chrome, web, css-selectors

While inspecting an element in Chrome I stumbled across this:

```
input[type="submit" i]:active
```

It's part of Chrome's user agent stylesheet. I've been doing web development since 2002 and I've never seen or noticed this before. It doesn't even seem to match what I thought the syntax was. Is this specific to Chrome? Is there W3C documentation on it? Upon trying to mess with it, it didn't seem to be behave any differently than writing this:

```
input[type="submit"]:active
```

I've been actively searching the web and have had zero luck finding anything. If anyone knows, I'd appreciate an answer.

P.S. The only thing I could think of is that it meant, "internal," though I simply don't know.

Comment: @NicholasR.Grant - It's a bit complicated. Praveen answered your question, but others in the community decided it was a duplicate of the one in the banner above your question. Unfortunately Paveen also decided to reopen it (he has that privilege because has a gold badge in one of the tags on your question) despite it being a duplicate and because he had an answer. This is no reflection on you - finding out whether your question has been asked before is hard and we're OK with having multiple questions as long as the answers are in one place.

Comment: Eeks... Sorry it was my mistake. :( Got it. It *is* a duplicate.